# How to detect window closing from right click->Close Window?

Tags: java, javafx-2

Is there an event that gets fired when somebody closes a desktop-based Java/JavaFx application  from the task bar (and not directly from the application itself) by right clicking on the application and executing Close Window?

Currently, if I close the window from the taskbar, the application window gets closed but the process does not get killed and keeps running in the background. I want to shut down the application completely, so that the Embedded Derby DB within the application gets disconnected.

I have tried the Stage's `setOnHiding()`, `setOnCloseRequest()` and other similar methods, but to no avail.

Thanks for all your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use ShutdownHook to free application resources.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()) {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                // write your code here 
            }
}
```

Comment: I think this solution would work for a Java application using a JFrame, mine on the other hand uses a JavaFx Stage that does not have a addWindowListener. Thanks, for posting though !